# Flutter: type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'bool'

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

I try to change my checkbox from false to true when it clicked but it return null is not a subtype of type bool.

Here's my code:

```
   // my function for checkbox
  void checkBoxChanged(bool? value, int index) {
    setState(() {
      db.folderTask[index].isChecked = !db.folderTask[index].isChecked;
    });
    db.updateDatabase();
  }
```

The error is here:

```
class FolderTask {
  String? name;
  bool isChecked = false;
  FolderTask({required this.name, required this.isChecked});
  factory FolderTask.fromJson(json) {
    return FolderTask(name: json['name'], isChecked: json['isChecked']);
  }
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "name": name,
        "task": [isChecked]
      };
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can provide default value on null case like,

```dart
return FolderTask(name: json['name'], isChecked: json['isChecked']??false);
```

Comment: Need to check the checkBox snippet, make sure to include the `value` . It would be easier if you can provide a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: glad to help, more about [null-safety](https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety)

Comment: yea i forgot to include the value. thank you sir :)